# how do I bake out a normal map from a procedural texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv, shaders

In blender I'm trying to use an emission shader to bake the color of a normal map of a procedural texture in blender like this[image]

everything is unwrapped but When I apply the baked out normal map a to the object as an image texture the shading looks very odd especially inside the pan [image]
My goal is to be able to convert procedural textures into texture maps that can than be applied using image textures and normal maps but I can't figure out why the baked normal map looks like this
here is the blend
[image]

Comment: There shouldn't be any Bump node between image texture and Normal map nodes, color there goes straight to color. If by "shading looks very odd" you mean banding then if it isn't fixed by above mentioned setup try baking into 16 bit color image instead

Comment: I think it's more the normals are baking odd but I can't figure out why the normals should look blue but instead I get different colors mixed in with them I think what's happening is the normals are baking in object space but I need them to bake in tangent space but I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: and the inside of the pan bottom looks reversed like the bottom is raising out of the surface which goes away when I use the procedurally generated material